# Выписать все варианты строк, подходящих под регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Привет всем. Есть регулярное выражение `((great)*grand)?((fa|mo)ther)`. Нужно написать все варианты слов, которые подходят под данное регулярное выражение. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из за квантификатора "`*`", ВСЕ наборы слов невозможно написать, вероятно там должен стоять символ "`?`".

[image]